# All That Remains Sudoku

Tags: grid-deduction, sudoku

```
 .  2  . | .  7  . | .  .  9 
 .  9  8 | .  .  . | .  .  . 
 3  .  . | 9  .  . | .  .  . 
---------+---------+--------
 2  .  7 | .  .  . | .  .  . 
 .  1  5 | 7  .  . | .  .  . 
 .  .  . | 1  5  8 | .  6  . 
---------+---------+--------
 .  .  . | .  3  6 | .  .  . 
 .  .  . | .  .  . | .  .  3 
 .  .  . | 4  .  5 | .  .  8
```

- Normal Sudoku rules apply
- When divided by 11 the 4 marked numbers (see example) have the same remainder

**Clarification**

This is an example of the remainder constraint:

```
 .  .  . | .  .  . | .  .  . 
 .  .  . | 9  5  2 | .  .  . 
 .  .  . | .  .  . | .  .  . 
---------+---------+--------
 .  3  . | .  .  . | .  1  . 
 .  2  . | .  .  . | .  3  . 
 .  5  . | .  .  . | .  8  . 
---------+---------+--------
 .  .  . | .  .  . | .  .  .
 .  .  . | 2  3  7 | .  .  . 
 .  .  . | .  .  . | .  .  .
```

Because:

- 952 = 86 x 11 + 6
- 138 = 12 x 11 + 6
- 237 = 21 x 11 + 6
- 325 = 29 x 11 + 6

```
 2  6  5 | 3  1  4 | 8  7  9 
 7  1  8 | 9  5  2 | 4  6  3 
 3  9  4 | 7  6  8 | 1  5  2 
---------+---------+--------
 6  3  7 | 8  4  9 | 2  1  5 
 8  2  1 | 5  7  6 | 9  3  4 
 4  5  9 | 1  2  3 | 7  8  6 
---------+---------+--------
 5  4  2 | 6  8  1 | 3  9  7 
 9  8  6 | 2  3  7 | 5  4  1 
 1  7  3 | 4  9  5 | 6  2  8
```

**Important**

The remainder in the example Sudoku is not necessarily the same as the remainder in the actual challenge.

The location of the special numbers is the same however.

Comment: That's an interesting variation: one that breaks the usual equivalence under digit/band/row/col permutations, and also one that allows puzzles with fewer than 17 clues.  Here's an example: .7....2.....83.......4........7....4.2.....5..........3...5.1..4.9...........26..

Comment: Starting from 17 clue puzzles, randomly permuting, restricting to those satisfying the remainder property, minimizing, and running this process for an hour, I find 1192 17-clue puzzles, 2160 16-clue puzzles, 217 15-clue puzzles, and 1 14-clue puzzle. Here's the one with 14 clues: .4.....6....51..................2...5.1......8..............1........8.5.26..4...

Comment: That was sort of my take on generating Sudokus. Trying to find a 'fun' constraint that will allow me to generate a Sudoku with minimal clues. I'm a software architect by profession.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Solution:
>
> ```
>  6  2  1 | 5  7  3 | 4  8  9
>  7  9  8 | 6  2  4 | 3  1  5
>  3  5  4 | 9  8  1 | 2  7  6
>  --------+---------+--------
>  2  6  7 | 3  4  9 | 8  5  1
>  8  1  5 | 7  6  2 | 9  3  4
>  4  3  9 | 1  5  8 | 7  6  2
>  --------+---------+--------
>  5  4  2 | 8  3  6 | 1  9  7
>  9  8  6 | 2  1  7 | 5  4  3
>  1  7  3 | 4  9  5 | 6  2  8
> ```
>
> As you can see, `624 % 11 = 613 % 11 = 536 % 11 = 217 % 11 =`**`8`**

Comment: Is that the only solution?

Comment: @JorisSchellekens As far as I can tell, it's unique.

Comment: rot13(Gurer vf va snpg nabgure fbyhgvba. Jvgu nabgure erznvaqre boivbhfyl.)

Comment: @JorisSchellekens Check again, I fixed a derp

Comment: Congratulations. You've found it.